# Map Postal Codes from BigQuery to DataStudio

Tags: looker-studio

I have Postal Codes in BigQuery as strings and I'm trying to map them in DataStudio.

When I do this for States and set the Geo Dimension as `Region Code` it works flawlessly.

But, when I do this for Zip Codes and set the Geo Dimension as `Postal Code` it loads the number in the legend bar (see graphic below) but it:

1. Doesn't map any of the points
   and
2. Doesn't allow me to select a Zoom Area

[image]

When I try to select the Zoom area, it states:

> This map needs a valid geo dimension before you can set the zoom area.

**How can I map Postal Codes (stored as strings) from BigQuery to DataStudio?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1) Postal Codes

Postal Codes are currently [supported](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9843174) in the [Google Maps](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713352) Chart.

Adding an image from the [Geo dimension reference](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9843174) Support Page for future reference:

[image]

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5340aa93-1ddd-439b-b7af-5fdcef8ef2b6) and a GIF to elaborate, using Postal Codes in the United States with [Google Maps](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713352) and [Geo Maps](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7065037):

[image]

### 2) Latitude Longitude

Whilst `Postal Codes` are currently supported in Google Maps, a `Latitude, Longitude` dimension is supported in both (Google Maps and Geo Maps), thus one approach is to link a `Latitude, Longitude` value to the respective `Postal Code` field.

I'll run through a possible workflow in Google Sheets to demonstrate:

1. Download data from [public.opendatasoft.com (US Zip Code Latitude and Longitude)](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/us-zip-code-latitude-and-longitude/table/) (has over 40,000 rows of data on `Postal Code` and a respective field in `Latitude, Longitude`);
2. Use the VLOOKUP function to link the Postal Codes from the current Data Set and [public.opendatasoft.com (US Zip Code Latitude and Longitude)](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/us-zip-code-latitude-and-longitude/table/) and then add the `Latitude, Longitude` values; have a look through the [Editable Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uE3g2Q_zvoWI12apiaYZVVcN6HbStnApv7KZhFIxBLU/edit?usp=sharing) for clarification;
3. [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144): Add the component and set the `Postal Code` field as the Dimension;
4. Geo Maps: Add `Latitude, Longitude` as the dimension and use the Filter Control to display the required area.

Added a [New Page to the Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5340aa93-1ddd-439b-b7af-5fdcef8ef2b6/page/w5yZB) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]